# Interstitial iAd doesn't show every time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad, interstitial

I am implementing interstitial ads in my iPhone app. I call the same block of code:

```
showInterstitialAds = true
self.interstitialAd.delegate = self
self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicy.Automatic
println(interstitialAd)
requestingAd = true
```

However, an interstitial ad is not shown every time - maybe once every 5 or 10 plays. Why is this?

Also, how can I check if an interstitial ad will not be shown, so that I can display a banner ad instead?

Answer (score 0):

The iAd platform serves ads to apps from an inventory of ads. The inventory available to any individual app depends on a lot of different factors, including the category of your app, whether your app cancels advertisements regularly, pricing and lots of other commercial factors that only Apple knows. Your app needs to handle the situation where you are not receiving an ad - as this will be a normal situation. My recommendation is to either have a standard set of your own ads, for example promoting features of your own app, or utilize another ad network to fill ads when iAd doesn't serve you one.

Here is a simple sample of how to hide or show ads depending on whether they were served or not:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    adView.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"Has ad, showing ad");
}


-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    adView.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"Has no ads, hidind ad");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I check if I'm not receiving an ad?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about 6 years old but I had the same problem. What worked for me (in Flutter):

```
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
bool _isInterstitialAdReady;

void prepAd(){
  initState();
  _loadInterstitialAd();
}

void runAd() {
  _interstitialAd.show();
}

void initState() {
  _isInterstitialAdReady = false;
  _interstitialAd = InterstitialAd(
    adUnitId: InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId,
    listener: _onInterstitialAdEvent,
  );
}


void _loadInterstitialAd() {
  _interstitialAd.load();
}
// TODO: Implement _onInterstitialAdEvent()
void _onInterstitialAdEvent(MobileAdEvent event) {
  switch (event) {
    case MobileAdEvent.loaded:
      _isInterstitialAdReady = true;
      break;
    case MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad:
      _isInterstitialAdReady = false;
      print('Failed to load an interstitial ad');
      break;
    case MobileAdEvent.closed:
      dispose();
      prepAd();
      break;
    default:
    // do nothing
  }
}

void dispose() {// TODO: Dispose InterstitialAd object
  _interstitialAd?.dispose();
}
```

I ran prepAd() once in the beginning and then just runAd() when I need it. You can check _isInterstitialAdReady == true inside runAd() if you want